# JAVA infinite server socket stopped for no reason

Tags: java, serversocket

I wrote a multi-thread server socket using an infinite loop for accepting client connections.
Each client connection would be handled by a thread.

The problem now is, after waiting for around 2 hours without any connections, the program would just stop for no reason (no exceptions).

timeout is set to infinite: setSoTimeout(0);
Here's the server socket code segment:

```
try {
        while(true) {
            socket = server.accept();
            BufferedReader ois = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter oos = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            SocketHandler socketH = new SocketHandler(socket, ois, oos, this);
            Thread socketT = new Thread(socketH);
            socketT.start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Debugger.log(e.getClass().toString() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

I'm really confused, any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try to catch Throwable. Maybe some JVM error getting out without a message.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem now is, after waiting for around 2 hours without any connections, the program would just stop for no reason (no exceptions).

I find this *extremely* hard to believe.  I think it is more likely that there is some improper exception handling than some sort of JVM fault.

- Are you completely sure that you'd see the output line in your `catch` all?
- Could you be running out of memory or other resources?
- Could some sort of operating system firewall be killing the dormant server socket?

One thing to realize is that when you do the following in the server loop, they may throw `IOException` there if the client connects and immediately closes the socket.

```
BufferedReader ois = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
BufferedWriter oos = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
```

I would recommend doing all of this *inside* the client thread.  Just pass in the `socket` into your `SocketHandler` constructor:

```
Thread socketT = new Thread(new SocketHandler(socket));
```

Then start your IO in the `run()` method of the `socketT`.

Another thing to try is to not do an `server.accept()` with a 0 timeout, but to set it to be a minute or something (`60000`) and catch `SocketTimeoutException` and then loop around.  This isn't the right thing to do long term but it might move the problem and expose the issue better.

Lastly, thy catching `Throwable` in your outer catch.  In terms of error handling, it's a gross thing to do but until you figure it out, you've got a dispensation.  :-)

Comment: Thanks, this is a memory consuming server, so when it's been idle for a while, linux kills it...